# free DNS hosting service (e.g. mybind.com / xname.org)

Tags: nameserver, g-suite, dns-hosting

(please note, I have not much knowledge about these things - so I might use some terms incorrectly)

I registered a domain name (only the name, no web hosting) and want to use it with google apps. Before I can do so, I need to have a name server where I can add a TXT record to prove ownership of the domain to google (as written here: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=60216).

So here are my questions:

- does anyone have any experience with http://mybind.com? It seems that this is exactly what I need, but:

  - is it reliable?
  - is it trustworthy (i.e. there's no way to contact the operator. the "contact us" link points to a site which is no longer available)?
- what if the mybind.com stops its service - can I move to a different DNS hoster any time?
- are there any alternative (free) services you can recommend?

**Update:** of course I need the DNS hosting not only to prove ownership, but also later for "normal" operation of my domain.

**Update 2:** I just found another free DNS hosting service: http://www.xname.org/. So any opinions about that provider are also welcome.

Comment: If it's free, it's probably pap.

Comment: If you really need the service you'll pay for it.

Answer (score 5):

As the owner of MyBind, I can't speak with objectivity, but:

- At least 1 out of the 2 nameservers is always online. For example, if the primary NS is offline for maintenance, then the secondary NS is still available ([RFC 2182](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2182.txt)).
- The contact page is now fixed, so you can easily request support/features/bug fixes.
- In the unlikely case I decide to stop hosting MyBind, you are free to move your records elsewhere (MyBind is just a record hosting service, and has no authority over your domain).
- For alternatives, search for "[free dns hosting](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=free%20dns%20hosting)" or visit [MyBind on Alternative.to](http://alternativeto.net/software/mybind/).
- xname.org is a "free **backup** DNS service"

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with mybind.com. But ANY company that has a dead contact us page ... well that's a *huge* red flag in my book. I would check out your registrar, most of them offer DNS hosting for free or a nominal fee.

Edit due to comment: 
I'd suggestion something like [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/custom/) don't forget this isn't just to prove ownership, but you will also have to host the A and CNAME records to point back to google while you are an apps customer.

Comment: Unfortunately my registrar doesn't offer that service.

Comment: +1 for DynDNS, I think Zerigo offer a free plan for <60k queries per month, also their pro plans are a bit cheaper ($29/year for 600k queries on Dyn, $19/year for 1mill queries on Zerigo) but I don't think Zerigo has the advanced features of Dyn

Comment: Zypher, the contact page is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I myself used to use everydns.net before they got bought by dyndns. Now however, I use cloudns.net.

They have support for everything btw. However, my sites aren't really that busy so I wouldn't know how much they support. Only 40GB of traffic per day so.....

Answer (score 1):

I had been using [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) from some time now and has been very reliable and simple, totally free and without limits. Please, note that they are a startup geared towards acting as a caching CDN for websites, but also offer totally free DNS hosting.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say anything about the other services, but I've been using [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org) for years now and I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to run the primary yourself, check out [BuddyNS](http://www.buddyns.com). They are free and the service is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Point](https://pointhq.com/). I've used it for at least two years now in over 10 domains and never had any problems. They've got 5 DNS servers distributed across the UK and US. They also have a feature to automatically add MX & SRV records for Google® mail & talk.

Plus their Control Panel interface is awesome and very easy to use.

Highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

[Hurricane Electri](https://he.net/)c has a [free dns service](https://dns.he.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EntryDNS](https://entrydns.net/). It has no limitations and is totally free.